# WebStorm plugin to explore Meteor's Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, webstorm

Is there any plugin allowing me to explore Meteor's MongoDB in a pretty user-friendly GUI way (like Robomongo)? I've looked at mongo plugin but it works with `mongod` itself and I dunno how to make it connect to Meteor's Mongo.

I would be extremely grateful for explanations how can I configure WebStorm for browsing Meteor's Mongo comfortably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. Use the mongo plugin and connect it to the URL you get when you:

1. Start Meteor.
2. In a different shell, cd to your project directory.
3. Enter `meteor mongo --url`

You need to have the MongoDB shell (this is the `mongo`commandline tool) installed on your machine. If you have installed the full MongoDB you already have it, if not you can select to install just the shell. All info available on the MongoDB website install instructions.

After having installed the mongo plugin in webstorm, you will find a tab called "Mongo Explorer" (usually on the right side of the window, depends on your WebStorm setup). Open this tab and click the "Mongo Settings" icon (looks like a wrench). Locate your mongo command executable, and add a server connection using the '+', specifying the URL as above.

Comment: I think OP is asking for a GUI.

Comment: Oh ok m'y bad! :-) please do you have a reference page and/or screenshot?

Comment: Thank you! Please, could you provide more verbose instructions how do I config and connect mongoplugin to a specific url?

Comment: I made the answer more detailed.

Comment: Thanks! Is it ok if meteor's mongo version differs from standalone one installed on my pc?

Comment: That is usually not a problem.